# How can I set the layout:width of an object to (wrap_content + 10)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-studio

I have a button in my Android app view, with a `layout:width` of `wrap_content` which automatically adjusts the width depending on the button's contents.

I want to apply some left-right padding to the button, so I want to add an extra 10px or so on top of the value of `wrap_content`.

How can I accomplish this in XML?

Comment: Why not use `android:layout_marginRight/Left`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the left and right [padding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3apaddingLeft)?

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
/>
```

Comment: Note that there seems to be some default padding. I didn't bother looking up what that value is, but I just put `10dp` on either side as an example.